# Dropdown Menu Breaks Sticky Footer

Tags: menu, footer, sticky

I have a footer with dynamic content & height, so i'm using the display:table version of sticky footer. The problem is I have a menu with an absolute positioned drop-down that extends past the footer if the page is too small, menu too big, etc. This creates a gap below the footer. Check out the fiddle for an example. Thanks.
http://jsfiddle.net/wmTn9/

Here's the css, although its easier to see in the fiddle.

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    background: turquoise;
    position:relative;
}
.menu {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:50%;
    background:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:20px;
}
.menu:hover {
    max-height:1000px;
}
.menu li {
    height:800px
}
.footer {
    display: table-row;
    background: lightgray;
}
.footer:hover h3 {
    height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, take `position:absolute;` out of the menu class and the footer will move down to accommodate the long menu.  If you want the footer to remain at the bottom of the browser window, add the following into your footer class...

```
width:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
```

`position:absolute;` takes the element out of the document flow. The element is then positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. Taking it out of the menu class puts the menu back into the document flow and stops the menu overlapping the footer.

[Amended Fiddle with footer stuck to the bottom of the browser window](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris1975/wmTn9/15/)